# Resolving IBus Issue - IBus prior to 1.5.11 may cause input problems

Tags: ubuntu, intellij-idea, phpstorm

I m using `PhpStorm 10` on `Ubuntu 14.04`.
I get the following error when at start :

```
8:08:47 AM IBus prior to 1.5.11 may cause input problems. See IDEA-78860 for details.
           Do not show again.
8:09:18 AM Platform and Plugin Updates: PhpStorm is ready to update.
```

How could I solve this, if any solution to upgrade `IBus` or change it with other library to do the same thing.

Comment: Before we wade thru these frustrating workarounds and fixes, what actual "input problems" do people experience? Has a backport of a more recent ibus been officially proposed for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Comment: @nealmcb Hi , yes indeed in the latest version typically i have tested it on 16.04 and above . you dont face such an issue unless you mess up with your systsem settings

Comment: But what are the issues for 14.04, with the older version? I hear people talk about them, but I've heard no specifics. If the issues are serious, I would hope that a solution would just be backported to 14.04.  If necessary I can see investing in the whole upgrade path, but not if it is just a minor issue.

Comment: I'm using CLion (related IDE using the same code base, same warning).  Periodically keyboard inputs stop working completely and I have to restart the IDE.

Comment: [I updated directly from Ubuntu 16.04's version](https://serverfault.com/a/882330/432437).

Answer (score 116, accepted):

if you use only one keyboard layout you can go to **Ubuntu**:
**System Settings -> Language Support**

*or if not found (f.e. mint desktop) search in main menu for language support*

and change **Keyboard input method** at the bottom of the page from **ibus** to **none**.

**Restart Ubuntu**.

It's the easiest way to fix this problem.

Comment: There is no such setting in PhpStorm 8.0.1

Comment: It's not in phpstorm but in Ubuntu

Comment: This did not solve my problem. Is there anything else that I can do?

Comment: see Nikita Mendelbaum response or http://serverfault.com/questions/735189/ibus-1-5-11-on-ubuntu/735381#735381

Comment: After disabling IBus in **System Settings** you would need to either restart your system or issues `killall ibus` in console.

Comment: I've tried out proposed solutions from the the above mentioned response at ServerFault, and while it worked for IBus package by itself, it also created quite nasty side issues. For instance I've completely lost the system settings menu and had to reinstall that with `sudo apt-get install unity-control-center`. Once reinstalled that also reverted IBus back to 1.5.5 version that is normally coming with Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: @Dragouf -- I'd recommend editing the answer to include your comment information. I almost missed this because I was in a hurry, and I'm sure many users would appreciate if you edited the answer to make it higher quality. +1

Comment: This is a workaround. The actual solution is posted by Uzair Faisal in this very same thread: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36158784/2186567

Answer (score 124):

**This solution is if you would like to upgrade ibus in Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS to the latest version (at the time of writing is 1.5.11).**

I recently had to install Intellij on a clean installed Ubuntu machine. These are the steps I took:

1. Install the dependencies

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libdconf-dev libnotify-dev intltool libgtk2.0-dev libgtk-3-dev libdbus-1-dev
   ```
2. Download the [ibus 1.5.11 source code](https://github.com/ibus/ibus/releases/download/1.5.11/ibus-1.5.11.tar.gz) (linked from [here](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/systemd/general/ibus.html))
3. Extract the files (`tar -xvf ibus-1.5.11.tar.gz`) and cd into the extracted folder
4. While in the ibus source folder, follow the instructions from step 1 to install ibus 1.5.11:

   ```
   ./configure --prefix=/usr --sysconfdir=/etc && make
   sudo make install
   ```
5. Restart Intellij IDE or whichever jetbrain's IDE that is in question

Comment: to be honest this is a long way to go compared to the answer

Comment: True, but this is the solution. The answer is a workaround

Comment: And workaround that works only for people that do not need features provided by ibus.

Comment: My thanks to Uzair and his sources @danielad long way? Took me ~3 minutes.  Compared to switching ibus off or dealing with intermittent keyboard freezes I just can't think of it as "long".

Comment: FWIW, on my box I also needed the libjson-glib-dev package (Elementary OS Freya)

Comment: the command `./configure --prefix=/usr --sysconfdir=/etc && make` seems encouter the json lib related issue, it is better to use what proposed by [IBus-1.5.14](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/systemd/general/ibus.html)

Comment: This drastically increased the debugging speed of my pycharm IDE

Answer (score 24):

Solution from [Jetbrains bug tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-78860):

> Either upgrade IBus to version 1.5.11 or add "export
>   IBUS_ENABLE_SYNC_MODE=1" to your ~/.profile, then restart a session.
>
> Alternatively, you can turn off IBus at System Settings | Language
>   Support | Keyboard input method.
>
> IDEA 15 will show a warning if an incompatible version of IBus is in
>   use.

Answer (score 13):

```
echo "export IBUS_ENABLE_SYNC_MODE=1" >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

For Ubuntu users, ibus 1.5.11 cannot be obtained easily unless Ubuntu 16.04 is released.

If you are using Ubuntu 14.04 and want to install ibus 1.5.11 here is the link to follow.

[How to properly update / install / compile ibus on 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/685745/how-to-properly-update-install-compile-ibus-on-14-04-dconf-problems/)

Answer (score 11):

Well, this is obviously a workaround, but on Ubuntu 14.04 calling:

```
ibus restart
```

Fix the problem... until it crashes again. At least you don't have to restart the IDE.

Comment: Well not so brillant. :) When doing this, you also have to select the correct keyboard setting you were using before (French for example). Just to mention that I don't have the problem any more with PhpStorm 2016.1. I think  "export IBUS_ENABLE_SYNC_MODE=1" finally worked for me.

Comment: If I have more IDE windows open, switching between them with alt+backtick immediately crashes the IDE after `ibus restart` has been called.

Answer (score 0):

*No idea if the following brought the solution but ...*

I had the same problem and i think every time i used `STRG+W` my keyboard stucked. Recently i changed:

`settings > code style > php > "set from ..." > predefined style > zend`

Since this day i did not had this bug anymore. *(perhaps it has nothing to do with it but rewrong a config somewhere ?)*

Answer (score 0):

`System Settings` -> `Language Support`

**or**

You can search it in Ubuntu's main menu for language support, after that change "Keyboard input method"(at the bottom of the page) from ibus to none and then - **Restart Ubuntu**.