# Android Studio - IBus prior to 1.5.11 may cause input problems

Tags: java, android, linux, android-studio

I am trying to set up Android development environment on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I downloaded Android Studio for Linux
(`android-studio-ide-141.2456560-linux.zip`).

[image]

Every time I launch the IDE, i encounter the following message:

```
IBus prior to 1.5.11 may cause input problem.
```

I did check this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33651898/resolving-ibus-issue-ibus-prior-to-1-5-11-may-cause-input-problems) and changed **Keyboard input method** at the bottom of the page from **ibus** to **none**. But that didn't solve the problem.

Also, the system requirement for installing the studio states that I need to have Oracle® Java Development Kit (JDK) 7  installed on my system. But, I am using Java 8 currently.

[image]

How do I fix the IBus issue and properly set it up with Java 7?

Comment: I'm already using Java8 for m

Comment: @piotrek1543 - Which means the studio works fine with java 8?

Comment: yes, works fine but you can't use some Java8 functions like lambdas